# How to obtain statistic from chisquare

Tags: python, scipy, chi-squared

For example when you enter

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
chisquare(f_obs=[175,25,125,125],f_exp=[133.3,66.7,166.7,83.3])
```

This returns

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=70.42153483789218, pvalue=3.4673013490296832e-15)
```

How do I get just the statistic (i.e. 70.42153483789218)?

Comment: Read the documentation, just save it to a variable and acess `.statistic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `.statistic` to access that attribute:

```
>>> chisquare(f_obs=[175,25,125,125],f_exp=[133.3,66.7,166.7,83.3]).statistic
70.42153483789218
```

Likewise, you can access `pvalue` in the same way:

```
>>> chisquare(f_obs=[175,25,125,125],f_exp=[133.3,66.7,166.7,83.3]).pvalue
3.4673013490296832e-15
```

Answer (score 0):

@sacul answer is great, and there's another way to get statistic only.

By using square brackets you can deal with that

```
>>> chi = chisquare(f_obs=[175,25,125,125],f_exp=[133.3,66.7,166.7,83.3])

>>> chi[0]
70.42153483789218

>>> chi.statistic
70.42153483789218
```

i hope you fid this useful and helpful